# How to submit a form using Java HttpURLConnection when button is image

Tags: java, html, forms, httpurlconnection

I am trying to write a program in Java using only the java.net.* libraries (i.e. HttpURLConnection, URL...) - this is a requirement for this project (i.e. no external packages like HttpClient, JSoup, etc...).  The ultimate form submission 'Go button' is actually a picture that the user clicks.  It's code snippet is here:

```
<script>
var form = $('pdb');
function proceed() {
form.submit();
}
</script>
<div id=input_nav>
<table class="nav_entry" onclick="proceed();" align=right>
<tr>
<td align="right">Next Step:<br/>Select Model/Chain</td>
<td align="right">Next Step:<br/>Select Model/Chain</td>
<td width="51" align="left"><img src="images/basic/next.png"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

To my understanding, form submission using Java's .net library requires sending the HTML' code's gui object name-value pairs, but as can be seen from the HTML source code snippet, no such fields exist foe the button.  Could someone please give me some direction with how this job can be accomplished?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is the issue exactly you are facing? - submitting the form on click of image? Or using `HttpURLConnection` on server side to invoke a service?

Comment: I want to know how I can use HttpURLConnection to click such image-if it is possible that is.  Therefore, more generally, I'd like to know if there exists a way to click such a form image that serves as a button using Java's native libraries.  I belive HttpURLConnection is the way to do it, but perhaps there are other ways too?